# What time zone should we follow for our flight from Vietnam to Bogota, Colombia via Turkish Airlines?

Tags: turkish-airlines, timezones

[image]

I'm a Filipino passport holder. If I book a flight via Turkish Airlines. What time zone should we follow? My country, Philippines? Turkey? Or Vietnam? Coz we will be departing from Vietnam. I'm super confuse coz those countries have different time zone. So, I don't know which time zone should I follow during our flight.

So, if our departure time in Ho Chi Minh, Vietnam is  21:10 or 9:10pm, we depart in Ho Chi Minh by 9:10pm on their time? And then arrival is 4:15am, Sept 16 in Istanbul. But, in Istanbul they're 4 hours late to Ho Chi Minh's time. So, 4:15am in Ho Chi Minh, In Istanbul it's 12:15am. So, we just still use Vietnam time for our next departure to Sao Paulo from Istanbul? Please check the time and date on the photo. 
I'm really confuse!!

Comment: I think we have a previous question about this somewhere, but the short version is that all times are local to the relevant airport.  You depart at 21:10 Vietnam time, arrive in Istanbul at 04:15 Istanbul time, depart again at 01:45 Istanbul time, and finally land at 7:30 Bogota time.

Comment: Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/65461/4188

Answer (score 9):

Departure and arrival times on air itineraries are always given as local time at the departure and arrival airport, respectively.

Your first flight departs SGN at 21:10 local time ([Indochina time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Vietnam), I believe). It arrives in Istanbul at 04:15 local time (Turkey time).  Turkey time is four hours *earlier* than in Vietnam, so when your flight lands in Istanbul, it will be 08:15 in Vietnam.  This matches the stated flight duration of 11 hours 5 minutes.

Likewise, your second flight departs IST at 01:45 Turkey time, and arrives at 07:30 Colombia time.  Colombia is eight hours earlier than Turkey, so it will be 15:30 Turkey time when you land - again, this matches the duration of 13 hours 45 minutes.